# what is interrupt masking and how is it implented in an assembly code?

Tags: assembly, pic

what is interrupt masking and how is it diffrent from polling and how is it used in a program and 
this piece of code is usually in and interrupt  routine code so wnated to ask what the code does XORWF PORTD,F

Comment: What exactly is your problem? Please be more specific?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that your question is related to PIC18 and its assembly language. Interrupt masking is letting certain interruptions to be handled or not, depending on what you want your PC or microcontroller to do under specific circumstances. Whenever a program gets an interruption, it will have to identify its source and execute the corresponding interrupt service routine.

The main advantadge of interruptions in relation to polling, is the fact that the processor will not waste clock cycles asking the input/output device if it is ready to receive data or if it has sent new data to be treated.

I do not understand the last question, you should reformulate it.